# Cakephp plugin layout is applying to all pages

Tags: cakephp

I am facing a strange error in cakephp2.0. I have created two layouts - one for plugin and one for front end users. Whenever I take the front end and after that if I take the plugin in the url, the front end layout is getting applied to all pages coming under plugin and vice verse. After 8-10 refresh it will take the correct layout. How to avoid caching of layout variable in this case ?

VideosController under app/Controller folder

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class VideosController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
         $this->layout = 'default';
         $this->set('videos', $this->Video->find('list'));
    }
}
```

My plugin Main controller

```
 class AdminAppController extends AppController
 {
      var $layout = 'admin';
 }
```

Another controller inside my plugin

```
 App::uses('AdminAppController', 'Admin.Controller');
 class VideosController extends AdminAppController 
 {

     public function index()
     {
         $this->Video->recursive = 0;
         $this->set('videos', $this->paginate());
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please post some relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set parts of your view to not be cached, or you could clear the cache every time the layout is changed. Check: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html